# How to create an Active Record join query

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sequel

I am using Sinatra and a Heroku-hosted PostgreSQL database. I have a query which works in Sequel:

```
@shortmembers = DB[:shortlists].distinct(:shortname).join(:shortmembers, :short_id => :listid)
```

How would I do that in Active Record?

In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(shortname), listid FROM shortlists INNER JOIN shortmembers ON shortlists.listid = shortmembers.short_id
```

And, can I do raw SQL queries with Active Record? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveRecord’s `select` and `joins`, which are documented on the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), you can do something *like*:

```
Shortlists.select(:shortname).uniq.joins(:shortmembers, :short_id => :list_id)
```

And yes, you can certainly do raw SQL queries with Active Record, but you’ll find that Active Record provides a method for most querying use cases, and those are preferable to raw SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am afraid this does not work. The error message says that relation "shortmembers" does not exist, but it does - in the database at least.